# Why does d3 always append to the body instead of my selection?

Tags: django, d3.js, django-staticfiles

I am using d3js in a django web app. I have a static js script that contains a function to render a visualization given some data (passed in the context) and a selection (e.g. `histogram(data,selection)`). Why would d3 ignore the passed selection and directly append to the body?

This is a simplified version of my code.

Template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'd3.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myd3vis.js' %}"></script>
<body>
 <div class="vis"></div>
 ...
</body>   
<script type="text/javascript">
 mselection = d3.select(".visualization")
 data = {{data|safe}}
 histogram(data,selection)
</script>
```

In myd3vis.js file I define the `histogram(data,selection)` function, which contains something like this:

```
svg = console.append("svg").attr({"class":"visualization",
       "width": 100,
       "height":200}) 
...
```

When the template loads, the visualization svg is always appended to the body, instead of being appended to the `<div class="vis">` element. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Try `d3.select('div.vis').append('svg')...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most browsers’ JavaScript environments, `console` is a global object unrelated to the DOM – it provides debugging functions (e.g. `console.log()`)… unless you’re clobbering it with a d3 DOM selection elsewhere, `console.append()` is unlikely to behave the way you seem to think it will.

Replace `console` with a bona-fide d3 selection, like:

```
var svg = d3.select('div.vis').attr(…); // et cetera
```

and inspect this object, to ensure your DOM logic is sound.

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear it.